# Simplifying an algebraic equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have three numbers which are as follows,

```
P = b + d + f
Q = ab + cd + ef
R = c * P = cb + cd + cf

Optionally;
S = (a + e) * P = ab + ad + af + eb + ed + ef

Note: The only known values are P, Q, R, S, c and f.
```

My question is, how can we find the value of `cd` only using `P`, `Q` and `R` (optionally using `S`)? 
Thank You!

---

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I basically tried `Q - R` and everything related around it.

Comment: You can't.  There are too many variables.  If, say, $(a,b,c,d,e,f)=(1,1,1,1,1,1)$ then $(P,Q,R,S)=(3,3,3,6)$ and $cd=1$.  Alternatively, taking $(a,b,c,d,e,f)=(1,0,1,2,1,1)$ then we also have $(P,Q,R,S)=(3,3,3,6)$ but this time $cd=2$.

Comment: @lulu Sorry there were some missing data. I corrected the question.

Comment: $\text{cd}=R -\text{cb}-\text{cf}$$

Comment: @Raffaele `cb` is unknown...

Comment: @DhirajWishal Your way of writing systems is quite confusing, you know. What are the unknown and what are the data?

Comment: @Raffaele Im sorry for making it way more confusing, the only data we know are P, Q, R, S, c and f.

Comment: @DhirajWishal 7 unknown $b,d,ab,cd,ef,cb,cf$ with three, (optionally) four equations? Forget it!

Comment: I don't understand.  My counterexample happens to have the same value for $f$ in both cases, so it is still a counterexample to the new data.  I mean, all you added was $f$, right?  We already knew $c$ from $\frac RP$  (ok, at least assuming that $P\neq 0$).

Comment: @lulu Yes, `f` is the only known value I added. I mean I marked `f` as a known value.

Comment: Right, so my original counterexample is still a counterexample.

Comment: @lulu Would adding `T = a + c + e` give any help?

Comment: Don't just guess at things.  Try to either solve for the things you want or try to find counterexamples.  As a general rule, solving for $6$ unknowns requires $6$ equations.  That doesn't always hold but it is at least a good guide.

Comment: @lulu Yeah there is a missing relationship in this that I need to construct. Ill look into it a bit more. Thanks for the help!